# Advanced day query with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have a problem with views in Couch DB (all versions 1.01 - 1.31).

My data looks like this :

```
{
   "_id": "9a12b7fa4b886640be06f74b814306a6",
   "_rev": "1-420c723f8c8f7921ead3df04bfc9ade5",
   "client_id": "008",
   "day": 1,
   "month": 1,
   "year": 2013,
   "comment": "cool"
}
```

And I want to see all transactions that client has done in a span of time, lets say 1 month :

so my map function is like :

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.client_id, doc.day,doc.month, doc.year], doc);
}
```

So I query with startkey and endkey like

```
http://localhost:5984/test/_design/clients/_view/by_cid_day_month_year?startkey=[%22007%22,1,1,2013]&endkey=[%22007%22,32,1,2013]
```

But instead of getting all documents from January with client_id = 007, I get all records matching 007.

So there has to be something that I am misunderstanding. What is wrong with my query ? How should it look ?

My thinking is that I could also just see logs from a specific date, or from say 1st jan to 6th jan.

I have tried to make the keys for day, month and year as strings, but the result is always the same, or even sometimes weird, like in the above example, I will find a record in September (9) but if I go to April f.ex. I get all records.

I don't understand this. This should be quite straight forward.

Comment: Not my strong suite, but shouldn't you `emit([doc.client_id, doc.year,doc.month, doc.day], doc);` (ie most significant first) to make the comparison work?

Comment: Odd, with the original, all days are between 1 and 32 so they'd be included before having to fall back to month (ie all days between 1 and 32 no matter the month would be included, so everything matching 007). With the new emit, I can't see how that would happen.

Comment: I'll try a few more times, your suggestion seems to work when using Firefox instead of chrome, I did try this before, but not using Firefox.

Comment: I did try this again, and it works now. Putting year first, month and finish with day works. Can you put in an explanation as an answer so I can give you answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the match goes from start to end and stops at the first chance, you'll want to emit the most significant search criteria first. In your original query you emit date before month which will lead to the date matching no matter what month or year it is.

If you instead;

```
emit([doc.client_id, doc.year, doc.month, doc.day], doc);
```

the comparison will first check year, then month and last date, which is what you mean to do.

As a side note, to match any date, I seem to remember that you could simplify your search to;

```
...by_cid_year_month_day?startkey=[%22007%22,2013,1]&endkey=[%22007%22,2013,1,{}]
```

...since leaving the last element out makes the array sort before any array that is longer (any date), and `{}` will sort after any date. Searching for entire 2013 would then in the same way be;

```
...by_cid_year_month_day?startkey=[%22007%22,2013]&endkey=[%22007%22,2013, {}]
```

Comment: Thanks. The empty hash thing is very useful